# Where did the 'static lifetime come from

Tags: rust

I've got the following code (doesn't make much sense, just a minimised test case):

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::json::Json;
use std::error::Error;

struct SomeStruct;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum SomeError<'a> {
    Something(&'a str),
    Other,
}

fn do_stuff(doc: &Json) -> Result<SomeStruct, SomeError> {
    Ok(SomeStruct)
}

fn get_things(doc: &Vec<Json>) -> Result<SomeStruct, Box<Error>> {
    let res = try!(doc.get(0).ok_or(SomeError::Other));
    Ok(try!(do_stuff(&res)))                             //// line 20
}

fn main() {
    let _ = get_things(&vec!(Json::Null));
}

impl<'a> std::fmt::Display for SomeError<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        write!(f, "blah")
    }
}
impl<'a> Error for SomeError<'a> {
    fn description(&self) -> &str { "blah" }
}
```

This fails with a type mismatch at line 20: `expected std::result::Result<SomeStruct, Box<std::error::Error + 'static>>, found std::result::Result<SomeStruct, Box<std::error::Error>>`

I don't understand where did the `'static` lifetime requirement come from suddenly. If I change the enum to use `Something(&'static str)` it works just fine, but why can't I use a less restrictive value here?

The error mentiones that `doc` is the borrowed content that the error cannot outlive... but there doesn't seem to be any relation between those two types.

Full error:

```
error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements [E0495]
  --> src/main.rs:19:24
19 |>     let res = try!(doc.get(0).ok_or(SomeError::Other));
   |>                        ^^^
src/main.rs:19:15: 19:55: note: in this expansion of try! (defined in <std macros>)
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 18:65...
  --> src/main.rs:18:66
18 |> fn get_things(doc: &Vec<Json>) -> Result<SomeStruct, Box<Error>> {
   |>                                                                  ^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:19:20
19 |>     let res = try!(doc.get(0).ok_or(SomeError::Other));
   |>                    ^^^
src/main.rs:19:15: 19:55: note: in this expansion of try! (defined in <std macros>)
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that types are compatible (expected std::result::Result<SomeStruct, Box<std::error::Error + 'static>>, found std::result::Result<SomeStruct, Box<std::error::Error>>)
 --> <std macros>:5:8
5 |> return $ crate :: result :: Result :: Err (
  |>        ^
src/main.rs:20:8: 20:28: note: in this expansion of try! (defined in <std macros>)
```

Comment: Could you please add the full compiler output to your question? It actually matters and isn't just noise :)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Attached. This code is complete for rust playground if you want to play with it. (http://play.integer32.com/?gist=57216402bc13d3acd623ccd47e89dda0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's quite a bit going on here. In order to explain it, let's look at this even more simplified version of your problem. To avoid hiding things, I also replaced the `try!()` with its [explicit form](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try!.html).

```
enum SomeError<'a> {
    Something(&'a str),
    Other,
}

// ... impls Debug, Display, Error for SomeError ...

fn do_stuff(doc: &u32) -> Result<(), SomeError> { Ok(()) }

fn get_things(doc: &Vec<u32>) -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    match do_stuff(&v[0]) {   // `try!` expands into this match 
        Ok(v) => Ok(v),
        Err(e) => Err(e.into()),
    }  //             ^^^^^^^^--- #1

}

fn main() {
    let _ = get_things(&vec![]);
}
```

This is the first thing that might be confusing: `try!` calls `std::convert::From::from(e)` (or equivalent, but shorter: `e.into()`). This means that the interesting spot is only the part marked with `#1`.

So what is going on *there*?

Calling `into()` means that the Rust compiler has to search for some implementation of `Into<Box<Error>>` for `SomeError`. Through the magic `impl<T, U> Into<U> for T where U: From<T>` indirection, the compiler finds a few implementations that might work out, notably this one:

```
impl<'a, E: Error + 'a> From<E> for Box<Error + 'a>
```

Here we see another key point: the type `Box<Error + 'a>` has a lifetime bound in it. The type in plain English would read something like: "a boxed type that implements the trait `Error` and is alive at least for the lifetime `'a`".

And now we look at our function signature and see `Result<(), Box<Error>>`: it doesn't have a lifetime bound in it! Well... we didn't explicitly write one out, but the compiler adds one anyway, because it's the only way to work with such boxed traits. [This RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0599-default-object-bound.md) is about default lifetime bounds that the compilers adds automagically. And for `Box<Trait>` the lifetime bound `'static` is added. Thus the return type explicitly written out is `Result<(), Box<Error + 'static>>`.

To make your code compile, add an explicit lifetime to the input parameter *and* to the output type, like so:

```
fn get_things<'a>(doc: &'a Vec<u32>) -> Result<(), Box<Error + 'a>> {
    ...
}
```

That way you can avoid the `'static` lifetime bound added by default and tell the compiler that the thing in your box only has to life as long as your input parameter.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. I ended up posting this case as a "this error doesn't really help" issue in rust as well (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35580)

Comment: Great answer Lukas. I know we're not supposed to write comments like this but.. it really is a great answer. So (thumbsup).