# Way to create inline static values

Tags: rust

Sometimes I'd like to use some complex values with static lifetime, but defining them explicitly is tedious. Is there a way to turn something like this:

```
const PATH: &'static [&'static str] = &["foo", "bar", "baz"];
...
    do_things(PATH);
```

into something closer to this?

```
do_things(&["foo", "bar", "baz"]);
```

The function takes a `&'static [&'static str]` argument.

Comment: If I may ask: why does the function's argument need to be `'static`? Why not a normal generic lifetime?

Comment: Because it's part of a solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884989/where-did-the-static-lifetime-come-from But this question is interesting to me on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing this *a lot*, and for a *specific* type of array, you can write a macro to simplify things:

```rust
// "Constant Array of STR"
macro_rules! castr {
    ($($es:expr),* $(,)*) => {
        {
            const C: &'static [&'static str] = &[$($es),*];
            C
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    test(castr!["a", "b", "penguin"]);
}

fn test(ss: &'static [&'static str]) {
    println!("{:?}", ss);
}
```

Comment: I do like this! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, at this time, there is not. You have to write your initial code.