# lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime so that the types are compatible

Tags: rust

I'm aware of [Where did the 'static lifetime come from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884989/where-did-the-static-lifetime-come-from) and [Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270052/cannot-infer-an-appropriate-lifetime-for-autoref-due-to-conflicting-requirements)。

But I still do not understand the problem I've encountered:

```
use std::ops::Index;

trait Stack<T> {
    fn as_slice(&self) -> &[T];
}

impl<T> Index<usize> for Stack<T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, i: usize) -> &T {
        &self.as_slice()[i]
    }
}

trait Core {
    fn stack(&self) -> &Stack<usize>;
    fn bad(&mut self) -> usize {
       self.stack()[0]
    }
    fn good(&mut self) -> usize {
       self.stack().as_slice()[0]
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

In the code above, `good()` gives no error, but `bad()` complains with:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
--> src/main.rs:18:14
|
18 |         self.stack()[0]
|              ^^^^^
|
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 17:5...
--> src/main.rs:17:5
|
17 | /     fn bad(&mut self) -> usize {
18 | |         self.stack()[0]
19 | |     }
| |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
--> src/main.rs:18:9
|
18 |         self.stack()[0]
|         ^^^^
= note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
= note: ...so that the types are compatible:
        expected std::ops::Index<usize>
            found std::ops::Index<usize>
```

There is no `Box` in this code, and I do not know where the static lifetime comes from.

Edit: through try and error I found the compiler assume Stack + 'static. The following code compiles. But why? Please point me to some document.

```
impl<'b, T> Index<usize> for Stack<T> + 'b {
    type Output = T;
    fn index<'a>(&'a self, i: usize) -> &'a T {
        &self.as_slice()[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: `fn stack(&self) -> &(Stack<usize> + 'static)` also fixes it, which suggests that you *could* implement `Stack<usize>` for a non-`'static` type in such a way that `bad` would indeed be bad.

Comment: The `'static` lifetime assumption is documented [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html?highlight=trait,object#inference-of-trait-object-lifetimes)

Comment: Thanks all of you. I now understand the cause of error.

Answer (score 4):

You are implementing a Trait (`Index`) for a Trait Object (`Stack<T>`).

The [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html#trait-object-lifetime-bounds) states:

> Since a trait object can contain references, the lifetimes of those references need to be expressed as part of the trait object. This lifetime is written as Trait + 'a. There are defaults that allow this lifetime to usually be inferred with a sensible choice.

If You don't define a lifetime the compiler assume a default, in this case it is assumed `'static` (see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes) for a detailed explanation)

Your code is equivalent to:

```
impl<T> Index<usize> for Stack<T> + 'static {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, i: usize) -> &T {
        &self.as_slice()[i]
    }
}
```

To resolve the `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements` compilation error just declare that `stack()` method returns a trait object with `'static` lifetime.

```
trait Core {
    fn stack(&self) -> &'static Stack<usize>;
    fn bad(&mut self) -> usize {
       self.stack()[0]
    }
    fn good(&mut self) -> usize {
       self.stack().as_slice()[0]
    }
}
```

Otherwise declare a generic lifetime for the `Stack<T>` trait object that impl `Index`:

```
impl<'a, T> Index<usize> for Stack<T> + 'a {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, i: usize) -> &T {
        &self.as_slice()[i]
    }
}

trait Core {
    fn stack(&self) -> &Stack<usize>;
    fn bad(&mut self) -> usize {
       self.stack()[0]
    }
    fn good(&mut self) -> usize {
       self.stack().as_slice()[0]
    }
}
```

At this point you should ask: why using `as_slice()` in `good()` works and using `index()` in `bad()` does not?

To make same sense of it try read the comments embedded in the MVCE below.

```
use std::ops::Index;

trait Stack<T> {
    fn as_slice(&self) -> &[T];
}

// equivalent to: impl<T> Index<usize> for Stack<T>
// just to expose the conflicting requirements error
// the right declaration is:
// impl<'a, T> Index<usize> for Stack<T> + 'a
impl<T> Index<usize> for Stack<T> + 'static {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, i: usize) -> &T {
        &self.as_slice()[i]
    }
}

trait Core {
    fn stack(&self) -> &Stack<usize>;
    fn bad<'a>(&'a mut self) -> usize {
       //self.stack()[0] syntactic sugar for:
       *self.stack().index(0)

       // self.stack() returns a trait object with a lifetime bound != 'static
       // but Stack impl for Index requires a 'static lifetime bound: 
       // COMPILE ERROR: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for
       // autoref due to conflicting requirements
    }
    fn good<'a>(&'a mut self) -> usize {
       // self.stack() returns a trait object with 'a lifetime bound
       // this is congruent with as_slice() lifetime requirements
       // see Catasta::as_slice() impl below
       // NO COMPILE ERROR
       self.stack().as_slice()[0]
    }
}

struct Catasta<T> {
    pila: [T;4]
}

impl<T> Stack<T> for Catasta<T> {

    fn as_slice<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a [T] {
        &self.pila
    }
}

struct RealCore {
    stk: Catasta<usize>
}

impl Core for RealCore {
    fn stack(&self) -> &Stack<usize> {
        &self.stk
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut core = RealCore {stk: Catasta {pila: [100, 2, 3, 4]} };
    println!("pos [0] item: {}", core.good());
}
```